I can't attach to a function of a web component in React
I am using a web component that I created myself with the @r2wc/react-to-web-component library.
This component receives as a parameter a function that is executed at a certain moment.
Then, from an app developed in react I import and use the component. But I can't stick to the function.
Web component:
type WCButtonProps = {
  text: string;
  color: string;
  sendData: (text: string) => void;
}

const WCButton: FC<WCButtonProps> = ({
  text,
  color,
  sendData,
}) => {

  return <>
      <button
          style={{ backgroundColor: color ? color : undefined }}
          onClick={() => sendData('Hello')}
      >
          {text}
      </button>
  </>
}

const RWCButton = r2wc(WCButton, {
  shadow: 'open',
  props: {
    text: "string",
    color: "string",
    sendData: "function",
  }
});

customElements.define("rwc-button", RWCButton);

React app:
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string | undefined>('Click me!');
  const [color, setColor] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const wcButtonRef = useRef<any>(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { current } = wcButtonRef;

    current.addEventListener('sendData', handleClick);

    return () => {
      current.removeEventListener('sendData', handleClick);
    }
  }, [wcButtonRef]);

  const handleClick = (text: string) => {
    alert(text);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <rwc-button ref={wcButtonRef} text={text} color={color}></rwc-button>
    </div>
  );
}

The text and color properties work perfectly, but sendData does not.
I also use the useEffect function instead of the UseLayoutEffect function. But it didn't work.
How can I fix this?

I don't get what current.addEventListener('sendData', handleClick) is supposed to do. You should rather pass sendData as a prop. There is no sendData event

If you are adding an event listener which listens to the sendData event, you need to dispatch it from your web component. Here is a link to how you can use and dispatch custom events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail. Additionally, provide a link to code pen and I can work from that and help you out better.

With CustomEvent it worked perfectly, thank you very much.
